# Fetch axios call only one time when render page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

What is the best way to call the REST API in the Ionic React application. I want to be run only once when the component first loads. It's requested to server again when go to next page and back again to same page. I want to reduce api call if same page call again.

```
function Projects() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getProjects();
    }, []);

    const getProjects = async () => {
        return api
            .getprojects()
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data.status) {
                    setProjects(response.data.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setMessage(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonContent>
                <div>
                    {projects.map(({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <strong>{item.title}</strong>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold your `projects` state in a parent component.  Global state can be managed with [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), but that is a little advanced.

For your example, the simplest way would be to hold the state in your parent component and pass `projects` in as props to the `Projects` component.

Something like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        projects.length === 0 && getProjects();
    }, []);

    const getProjects = async () => {
        return api
            .getprojects()
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data.status) {
                    setProjects(response.data.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setMessage(error);
            });
    };
    return (
       <Projects projects={projects}/>
    )
}
```

And in Projects, remove that code:

```
function Projects({ projects }) {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonContent>
                <div>
                    {projects.map(({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <strong>{item.title}</strong>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```